As root user, why do most commands fail unless sudo is used?

why is this happening?

Expected output:
# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500......

Output that occurs:
# ifconfig
bash: ifconfig: command not found

If sudo is used it works:
# sudo ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500......


Can this effect startup scripts that use something located in /sbin?


your PATH variable is not set properly.

How did you become the root user? Both sudo -i and su - should set the correct path, as well as a direct login. su (or worse sudo su) will not reset the path.

From ssh I log in as normal user, then su root, I thought my path would change, but its the same as normal user.

"command not found" means exactly that.
Your shell could not find an executable file called ifconfig in any of the places that it looked for executables files.
This will probably error in the same way:
which ifconfig 

Examine the PATH environment variable:
echo ${PATH} | tr : "\n"   # More readable 

It is possible for start-up scripts (like .login and .bashrc) and interactive actions to "mess up" the PATH, even removing [system critical] entries like /sbin!
When using sudo to launch ifconfig as root, it starts up a new shell session, which will have its own, "clean" PATH, which might well explain why that method is working.

Thanks, so I have 2 servers that are mostly identical. One is messed up, so on the working one I tested your suggestion.
As normal user: $ /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/local/games /usr/games
su root:              # /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/local/games /usr/games
su -                    # /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin
Is this proper behavior for Debian Bookworm? Maybe I need to relearn and never use su root, but su -. Thanks

Well I just found this from 2018 https://sources.debian.org/src/util-linux/2.33.1-0.1/debian/util-linux.NEWS/
Guess I am behind the times, and this seems hard to get used to.
